# Are we limited to 3300-3400 threads/process in 64-bit Windows system?

Tags: multithreading, qt

Following along [Threaded Fortune Server Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-threadedfortuneserver-example.html) I've created a similar server that receives `json` object from clients and it can handle around 3330 clients simultaneously without any issue.

If I increase the number of clients to 3400, I get:

```
CreateWindow() for QEventDispatcherWin32 internal window failed (The current process has used all of its system allowance of handles for Window Manager objects.)
Qt: INTERNAL ERROR: failed to install GetMessage hook: 1158, The current process has used all of its system allowance of handles for Window Manager objects.
```

How can I increase number of threads?

---

**EDIT**

---

Instead of `FortuneThread` I have `ClientThread` like this:

```
class ClientThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ClientThread(qintptr socketDescriptor);
    void run() override;
signals:
    void readyRemove();
private:
    qintptr socketDescriptor;
};
```

and in `run()` I am creating client:

```
void ClientThread::run()
{
    Client c(socketDescriptor);
    emit readyRemove();
}
```

and the `Client` is as usual:

```
class Client : public QTcpSocket
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Client(qintptr descriptor);
public slots:
    void onReadyRead();
    void onError(QTcpSocket::SocketError error);
};
```

and implemented as:

```
Client::Client(qintptr descriptor)
{
    connect(this, &Client::readyRead, this, &Client::onReadyRead);
    connect(this, static_cast<void (Client::*)(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)>(&QAbstractSocket::error), this, &Client::onError);
    setSocketDescriptor(descriptor);
    waitForDisconnected();
}

void Client::onReadyRead()
{
    QVariantMap map = QJsonDocument::fromJson(readAll()).object().toVariantMap();
    qDebug() << map["Name"].toString() << map["Age"].toInt();
}

void Client::onError(SocketError error)
{
    if(state() == ConnectedState && error == SocketTimeoutError)
        waitForDisconnected();
}
```

Ofcourse, `onReadyRead()` can be problematic in this way. `Server` class takes care of `ClientThread`. It stores each client thread in a `QVector` and removes it when disconnected from host and here is its header:

```
class Server : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Server(qint16 port, QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Server();
protected:
    void incomingConnection(qintptr descriptor) override;
public slots:
    void removeClient();
private:
    QVector<ClientThread*> clients;
};
```

and `incomingConnection` and `removeClient` do these:

```
void Server::incomingConnection(qintptr descriptor)
{
    ClientThread *thread = new ClientThread(descriptor);
    connect(thread, &ClientThread::readyRemove, this, &Server::removeClient);
    thread->start();
    clients.push_back(thread);
}

void Server::removeClient()
{
    ClientThread *thread = (ClientThread*)sender();
    thread->quit();
    thread->deleteLater();
    clients.removeOne(thread);   
}
```

To test the Server application I've used the following Console application:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QVector<QTcpSocket*> clients;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3300; i++){
        QTcpSocket *sock = new QTcpSocket();
        sock->connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 2000);
        sock->waitForConnected();
        clients.push_back(sock);
    }
    QJsonObject obj;
    obj["Name"] = QString("TestName");
    obj["Age"] = 1;
    QJsonDocument doc(obj);

    foreach (QTcpSocket *s, clients) {
        s->write(doc.toJson());
        s->flush();
    }

    foreach (QTcpSocket *s, clients) {
        s->close();
        s->deleteLater();
    }
}
```

Comment: how you are implementing thrading ..

Comment: From the message I'd say that aren't really out of threads, but probably of window handles, which Qt uses on Win32 for events dispatching. Still, using so many threads is a bad idea on many regards. If you have such a high number of clients you should switch to a thread pool based architecture or plain asynchronous IO.

Comment: @MohammadKanan, I've included code in my post for your review.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, can you please provide some reference link to implement server in that way.

Comment: You may find interesting [this series](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/concurrent-servers-part-1-introduction/) by Eli Bendersky.